# Partially apply a CreditMemo on NetSuite API

Tags: apply, netsuite

im working on an integration between our company systems and NetSuite using PHP. Before the newest release of the NetSuite platform we were able to partially apply an existing credit memo to an specific pending invoice, but since their last release a couple of weeks ago every time we try to apply the credit to an specific invoice through our middle PHP system, it also applies all the other pending invoices in the account.

Let me specify a little more:

We have customer accounts, every account can have any number of open invoices. Lets say we have 3 invoices in the account 1. The first is for $20, the second for $30 and the last for $25. Then we create a credit memo associated to the account 1 for $75.

Then a week later we want to kill the first invoice of the account 1, the one with the $20 value. Then we command the credit memo to kill that invoice through our system. That would mean the first invoice is cancelled, we used $20 from the $75 we had in the credit and we still have $55 without use. Right?

Well, now for some reason the credit kills all the 3 invoices the account 1 had pending, even though we specify that only the first one should be applied. That consumes all the $75 of the credit memo, which of course messes up our accounting and prevents us from using it later in other invoices as we need it.

Just a few more points:

- We are uploading our credit memos with property "autoapply" set on false.
- When we want to apply an invoice we set its "apply" property as true and the ones from the other invoices as false, then we make an update request for the credit memo with that info. Thats how we always did it but now for some reason it doesnt works.

Sorry if its a little long, but i wanted to be really specific. If you have had a similar problem or have any insight on the matter i would greatly appreciate any help you can give. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion you can try as I have experienced this as well. I had an issue where the user whose log in I was using for the integration entered a new credit memo, checked the box to auto apply and from then on every CM I imported through web services auto applied and did not respect the Auto Apply setting I submitted.

Log in as the user that you are authenticating with for the integration. Open a new credit memo and see if the Auto Apply check box is checked by default. This is a "sticky" setting in NetSuite. Enter a new CM As the user with the box unchecked and then delete it if you like. When I did this it stopped checking the box automatically and my CM import worked as expected again.